# Export root site content types and selected properties to csv

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, content-type

I want to recreate a clients' ct structure using VS2012 so some cts and their guids 
I did have a go but it would be nice only to add the properties I want to my csv file rather than whole lot.. Any suggestions please

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://myclient.local/

$web = $site.RootWeb

$psObject = New-Object psobject
foreach ($ctype in $web.ContentTypes) 
{
  $OutputString = $ctype.Name,$ctype.Group,$ctype.Id, $ctype.Description 

Add-Member -InputObject $psobject -MemberType noteproperty -Name $ctype.Name -  Value $ctype  

#$ExportInfo += $ctype.Name
#$ExportInfo += $ctype.Group
#$ExportInfo += $ctype.Id
#$ExportInfo += $ctype.Description
```

}

```
     $psobject | Export-CSV c:\dev\Ctlist4.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://myclient.local/

$web.ContentTypes | Select-Object Name, Group, Id, Description | Export-Csv c:\dev\Ctlist4.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks... I think I need learn that short hand for describing an object....